# Teradata & Tableau Query Issue

Tags: tableau-api, teradata

**Getting a following error on Tableau for my Teradata Query**

[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseSyntax error: ORDER BY is not allowed in subqueries.

**Even after removing the ORDERBY, I get the following error**
[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseSyntax error: All expressions in a derived table must have an explicit name.

[Pleas see my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsnRF.png)

Comment: Don't post screen captures / images. Post as text. Seems that your query is submitted by Tableau as part of a larger query. You need to assign an alias to the COUNT

Comment: Tableau seems to warp your Select in a Derived Table. Simply add an alias to the COUNT (as the error message implies)

Answer (score 1):

Tableau, Teradata and ORDER BY don't jive, but you can order once you're in Tableau without the ORDER BY in the query.

For the explicit name, you need to be sure all aggregated columns are given a column name or alias.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the 'ORDER BY' from the query in Teradata and then SORT the rows in Tableau. You also need to explicitly name all the columns calculated within your query. So you will have to replace

```
COUNT(MKTMSTVIEWS.s_360_umart_order_activity.BAN)
```

with something like

```
COUNT(MKTMSTVIEWS.s_360_umart_order_activity.BAN) AS CNT_BAN
```

in your code.